# terminar la ejecución condicionalmente en Java

Tags: java, bucles

Ingresar los datos de n alumnos(cortar con “fin*”).El curso puede ser A o B.Nombre, curso, nota, sexo, edad. Calcular e imprimir:

1. Cantidad de alumnos aprobados (se aprueba con 6), por curso.
2. Cantidad de alumnos aplazados, por curso.
3. Edad promedio, general y por curso.
4. Nota promedio de los alumnos varones, por curso.
   Mostrar los resultados por pantalla utilizando ventanas a través de la clase JOptionPane.

NO SE COMO IMPRIMIR LOS RESULTADOS POR VENTANA(jOPTIONPANE) Y CREAR EL CORTE "FIN" CON UNA PREGUNTA.

---

```
 package tp;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class datos {public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i, edadA=0, edadB=0, cantA=0,cantB=0,edadG=0,notVA=0,notVB=0,cantVA=0,cantVB=0;
    double predadA, predadB,predadG,prnotVA,prnotVB;
    int notA=0, notB=0, cantaprA=0, cantaprB=0,cantaplA=0,cantaplB=0,canteG=0;

    int nota[]; 
    nota = new int[8];

    String nombre[];
    nombre = new String[8]; 

    String curso[];
    curso = new String[8]; 

    String sexo[];
    sexo = new String[8];

    int edad[]; 
    edad = new int[8];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(i=0;i<8;i=i+1)
                {
    System.out.printf("Ingrese nombre alumno %d: ",i+1 ); 
    nombre[i] = input.next();
    System.out.printf("Ingrese curso alumno ( A/B) %d: ",i+1 ); 
    curso[i] = input.next();
    System.out.printf("Ingrese nota alumno %d: ",i+1 ); 
    nota[i] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.printf("Ingrese sexo alumno (F/M) %d: ",i+1 ); 
    sexo[i] = input.next(); 
    System.out.printf("Ingrese edad alumno %d: ",i+1 ); 
    edad[i] = input.nextInt();

    // EDAD PROMEDIO GENERAL

    edadG=edadG+edad[i];
    canteG=canteG+1;

    // EDAD PROMEDIO POR CURSO

    if (curso[i].equals("a")|| curso[i].equals("A") ){ 
        edadA= edadA+edad[i];
        cantA=cantA+1;     }

      else { 
          edadB=edadB+edad[i];
          cantB=cantB+1;   }

    // APROBADOS POR CURSO

    if (nota[i]>=6){
          if ( curso[i].equals ("a")|| curso[i].equals ("A")){
          notA=notA+nota[i];
          cantaprA=cantaprA+1;    }

          else {
          notB=notB+nota[i];
          cantaprB=cantaprB+1;  }

    }

    // APLAZADOS POR CURSO

    if (nota[i]<6){ 
          if ( curso[i].equals ("a")|| curso[i].equals ("A")){ 
          notA=notA+nota[i];
          cantaplA=cantaplA+1;
    }
    else { 
          notB=notB+nota[i];
          cantaplB=cantaplB+1;
    }
    }

    // NOTA PROMEDIO VARONES POR CURSO

    if (sexo[i].equalsIgnoreCase("m")) {

        if (curso[i].equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
        {
             notVA=notVA+nota[i];
             cantVA=cantVA+1;
        }else { 
               notVB=notVB+nota[i]; 
               cantVB=cantVB+1;   
    }
    }                      
        }   // aca termina el for

                   // imprimir calculos

        predadG=edadG/canteG;   
        System.out.print( "El promedio general de edad es: " + predadG + "\n" );

        predadA=edadA/cantA;
        System.out.print( "El promedio de edad del curso A es: " + predadA + "\n" );

        predadB=edadB/cantB;
        System.out.print( "El promedio de edad del curso B es: " + predadB + "\n");

        System.out.print( "La cantidad de alumnos aprobados en el curso A es de: " + cantaprA+ "\n");

        System.out.print( "La cantidad de alumnos aprobados en el curso B es de: " + cantaprB+"\n");

        System.out.print( "La cantidad de alumnos aplazados en el curso A es de: " + cantaplA+"\n");

        System.out.print( "La cantidad de alumnos aplazados en el curso B es de: " + cantaplB+"\n");

        prnotVA=notVA/cantVA; 
        System.out.print( "El promedio de alumnos varones en el curso A es de: " + prnotVA+"\n");


        prnotVB=notVB/cantVB;
        System.out.print( "El promedio de alumnos varones en el curso B es de: " + prnotVB+"\n");



  }
}
```

Comment: La idea es que aquí te podamos ayudar, siempre y cuando tu hayas hecho algún progreso con el problema. Te recomiendo avanzar algo y postear ese código o postear al menos la lógica que has pensado plantear.

Comment: No entiendo como hacer que el corte sea "fin"

Comment: Adriana, aquí el punto es que no se aprecia que hayas realizado ninguno de tus cálculos, si lo que deseas es detener la inserción de datos al momento de escribir "fin" puedes evaluar una variable (puede ser nombre) en una condición, if(!nombre.equals("fin")) { realiza mis cálculos } , si el nombre es igual a "fin" entonces no hará los cálculos dentro del if.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que la cantidad de alumnos es "n" te aconsejaría usar ArrayList, para poder hacerlos dinámicos. Para el ArrayList, podrías crear una clase de tipo estudiante, con los parámetros que necesitas, y en la clase donde haces los calculos creas un ArrayList de tipo "Estudiante".

```
ArrayList<Estudiante> estudiantes = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();


String nombre = "";

while(!nombre.equals("fin")){
        System.out.printf( "Ingrese nombre alumno %d\t",i+1 );            
        nombre = input.next();
        System.out.printf( "Ingrese curso alumno %d\t",i+1 ); 
        String curso = input.next();
        System.out.printf( "Ingrese nota alumno %d\t",i+1 ); 
        int nota = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf( "Ingrese sexo alumno %d\t",i+1 ); 
        String sexo = input.next(); 
        System.out.printf( "Ingrese edad alumno %d\t",i+1 ); 
        int edad = input.nextInt();

estudiantes.add(new Estudiante(nombre, curso, nota, sexo, edad);
}
```

Comment: le faltó el `*`